# Copy only some subdirectories

Tags: windows, powershell, xcopy, total-commander

I have a large and deep directory structure and I want to copy only some specific subfolders. Like for example, copy only (minimatch notation) `./foo/bar/baz/**/*` and `./bar/foo/**/*` but exclude everything else.

I know I can specify what to copy in the copy dialog (F5) and I can *exclude* some folders in the fied "Only files of this type:" using `| MyFolderToExclude\`, but that doesn't help.

I this is not possible with total commander, what would be another esay and quick way to this (e.g. using a powershell or xcopy)?

Comment: You could use the -depth parameter on get-childitem. I'm not sure this is exactly what you are looking for though?
get-childitem c:\foo -recursive -depth 2. I think -depth came around in PowerShell 3 or 4. As long as you have those versions, you should be ok.

Comment: Unfortunately `-depth` doesn't work. The folders I want to copy have arbitary  depths. And I do want to omit other folder with the same depth.